# MySQL timezone discrepancy on Update tale

Tags: mysql, timezone

I'm working on a shared hosting so I don't have access to mysql configuration files.

The default timezone on that system is 'America/New_York' but I need to use UTC -5:00 for my databases.

Everytime I perform a query the timezone is set to UTC -5:00 like this:

```
SET time_zone='-5:00';
```

If I want the current time, **SELECT NOW()** returns the correct time and date, but when updating a table mysql uses the SYSTEM time and not the set timezone

```
UPDATE administradores SET ultimo_acceso=NOW() WHERE id=1
```

Why does those values are different? Shouldn't be the same time in both queries since I'm overriding the timezone?

I also tried with INSERT statement and that works fine.

Comment: I'm not sure, but when you set something you are doing it locally, I think that you need to set it as global http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//time-zone-support.html take a look to that URL

Comment: `America/New_York` is at UTC-05:00 during part of the year and UTC-04:00 during daylight savings time.  Are you sure you want to disable DST?  Also - what is the exact data type of `ultimo_accesso`?

Comment: @MattJohnson yes I want to use in fact Mexico City timezone which I think is US Central time. ultimo_acceso is a TimeStamp

Comment: Then you probably want to use `America/Mexico_City` for the time zone id.  It switches between -6 and -5.  [See this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Comment: [This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Mexico) may also be informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `ultimo_acceso` field is of type `TIMESTAMP`, then the value is actually being stored as UTC and then converted back to the current time zone when you select the value  back out.  So you need to set the time zone again in the select statement.

If you are using a `DATETIME` data type, then the value you set should be persisted without conversion and you will get back exactly what you store - regardless of the timezone setting at time of select.

[See the MySQL docs on this subject](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html).

Comment: You're right the value on database is stored as SYSTEM timezone but when querying with different timezone the change is done.

Comment: This would be a problem working directly on database but with PHP there should be no problem. Thank you

Comment: @JorgeZapata - It's actually stored in UTC. It's just that the system timezone is the default if you don't set it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `DATETIME`, `DATE`, and `TIME` fields will always return the exact time you placed into them, regardless of the value of the `time_zone` variable.

`TIMESTAMP` fields *will* automatically convert their values to the timezone specified by the `time_zone` variable.

Comment: I'm using TIMESTAMP field, isn't supposed to use the SESSION time_zone value?